# Move to a next line if there is no space

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML code where when the text is too long, it should move the next line. But now, it is getting extended with horizontal scroll bar. Can we avoid this scroll bar and make sure it enters the next line

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">dfsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
```

Comment: You should use "overflow-wrap: anywhere;"

Answer (score 8):

Use `word-break: break-all` BUT be careful, this will break wherever it needs to, doesnt take words or something in account.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">dfsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
```

Comment: you can also use something "smaller" and add: word-wrap: break-word, and add overflow:hidden; for this div - it won't break everything like "ssss x 1000" but will also not show nothing that will break div width ...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Fabian's answer, you can also use `word-break: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word;` if your text consists of multiple words, it would break the words only if it's necessary

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  word-break: normal;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec sapien nisl. Aenean nisl elit, vehicula sed erat ac, vestibulum.</div>
```